# Removing leading and trailing spaces in Excel

Tags: macos, excel, spaces, vba

I am looking to clean up my data in an Excel worksheet and remove leading and trailing spaces from my data. I have found the following code that has already answered a similar question:

[How to remove leading and trailing spaces from all cells of a excel sheet at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181405/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-all-cells-of-a-excel-sheet-at-onc)

```
Sub KleanUp()
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
v = r.Value
If v <> "" Then
  If Not r.HasFormula Then
    r.Value = Trim(v)
  End If
End If
  Next r
End Sub
```

However, I am getting an error with the line:  If v <> "" Then

I'm sure I've got this code to work for me in the past, but now I can't work out why this error is occuring. If anyone has any thoughts..

Comment: what kind of variable is V?What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be a cell with an error in (i.e. #REF!, #N/A, #VALUE, etc.)

try this:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsError(r.Value) Then
            v = r.Value
            If v <> "" Then
                If Not r.HasFormula Then
                    r.Value = Trim(v)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this work perfectly!!! You're right... I did have some cells with an error in them,